# error Xcode 7.3.1 Swift 2 Parse not found when testing

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I have imported Parse framework to my app and it correctly compiles for the code files.  However, when I try to use Parse for my tests, I got the following error:

> ld: framework not found Parse for architecture x86_64 clang: errror: linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)

I have checked in build settins search paths, and it seems to have the right values, and Parse works fine in code file.  It is only in the tests files that I get the error.

Any hint appreciated.

the test file is:

```
@testable import Project
import Parse
import XCTest

class ProjectUITests: XCTestCase {

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    continueAfterFailure = false
    XCUIApplication().launch()
  }

  override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the parse module and on the right side of Xcode you'll see something called Targets. Select uitest or unit test and build.

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding! :)